# Ruby: How do I make a loop that prints an array index position's contents UNLESS it's the same as the last position's?

Tags: ruby, arrays

Here's my array:

```
num_arr = ["cat","dog","penguin","penguin"]
```

I want to print each index position's contents unless those contents are the same as the contents of the last index position. In this case, that would be a loop that prints...

```
["cat","dog","penguin"]
```

EDIT: I mean I'd like to print everything up to the last element UNLESS the last element is identical to the second-to-last element. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know how to get the contents of the `last` item?

Comment: Your edit changes the nature of the question since it breaks your rule.

Comment: The spec is difficult to understand. Why are you saying "index position's contents" rather than "element"? Do you just want to pop the last element off the end of the array? What's the expected output for the input `["cat", "dog", "dog", "penguin", "penguin"]`?

Comment: Shouldn't "penguin" never be printed since it's the last value?

Comment: "last" in the sense of the last element of the array or "last" as the previous element in the loop?

Comment: Ah, sorry. I meant to say "element", instead of "index position's contents." And I mean I'd like to print everything up to the last element UNLESS the last element is identical to the second-to-last element. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Based on your edit, I hope you won't use any of the solutions that involve iterating over the entire array just to compare the last two values. Go with the answer from @tokland or something similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this?

```
num_arr[0...-1] + (num_arr[-2] == num_arr[-1] ? [] : [num_arr[-1]])
```

Less verbose, but somewhat more difficult to undestand:

```
num_arr[0...-2] + num_arr[-2..-1].uniq
#=> ["cat", "dog", "penguin"]
```

Comment: can the downvote explain the reason so I can refine the answer?

Answer (score 2):

```
foo = ["cat","dog","penguin","penguin"]
=> ["cat", "dog", "penguin", "penguin"] 

answer = foo.reject { |ele| ele == foo.last }
=> ["cat", "dog"]
```

I believe this is what you're asking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
new_array = array.each_with_object([]) { |element, result| result << element unless result.last == element }
new_array.each { |element| puts element }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to print all **unique entries** use the `uniq` [method of Array](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-uniq) in this case.

```
["cat","dog","penguin","penguin"].uniq.map{|a| p a}
```

console

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :004 > ["cat","dog","penguin","penguin"].uniq.map{|a| p a}
"cat"
"dog"
"penguin"
 => ["cat", "dog", "penguin"]
```

### **Update:**

If you want to only do a **comparison for the last entry**, you could do that by storing the last entry in `@prev` and assigning it after the comparison to the current entry.

```
["cat", "dog", "penguin", "penguin"].map{|a| p a if @prev!=a;@prev=a }
```

console

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :009 > ["cat", "dog", "penguin", "dog", "penguin"].map{|a| p a if @prev!=a;@prev=a }
"cat"
"dog"
"penguin"
"dog"
"penguin"

ruby-1.9.2-p290 :010 > ["cat", "dog", "penguin", "penguin"].map{|a| p a if @prev!=a;@prev=a }
"cat"
"dog"
"penguin"
```

Comment: That is incorrect for an array like `["cat", "dog", "dog", "penguin", "penguin"]` which should yield `["cat", "dog", "dog"]` or `["cat", "dog", "dog", "penguin"]` depending on how you interpret the question.

Comment: @benzado I just made my own interpretation of his problem since its quite unclear. If the desired result is how you describe, above method is useless offcourse. it could also be that he wants `["cat", "dog", "penguin", "dog", "penguin"]` to just yield `["cat", "dog", "penguin", "dog", "penguin"]` which also wont work with above method.

Comment: This will produce unique values across the entire array e.g. `['a', 'b', 'a']` should emerge unmodified.